# How can I pass multiple config key-value pairs to git clone?

Tags: git, configuration, git-clone

I would like to pass multiple key-value configurations to `git clone`. The [`git-clone` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) only tells me that

> If multiple values are given for the same key, each value will be written to the config file.

However, what I want to do is set, not multiple values to a key, but multiple key-value pairs.

For example, I would like to set `core.autocrlf=false` and `core.filemode=false`. How should I use `git clone`'s `-c` option to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply invoke the `--config`/`-c` flag for each of your key-value pairs. In this case,

```sh
git clone -c core.autocrlf=false -c core.filemode=false <url>
```

will do the trick, as evidenced by the test below:

```sh
$ git clone -c core.autocrlf=false -c core.filemode=false https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags
$ cat gitdags/.git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
    autocrlf = false
    filemode = false
...
```